# JBOSS 7.1.1 deployment error "Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."

Tags: java, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

I get this error when try to deploy my application using IntelliJ IDEA 13:

```
13:16:10,610 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011448: Failed to parse "/C:/serwers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/XXX-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml"
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.parse(PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve expression: ${XXX.datasource}
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.PropertiesValueResolver.replaceProperties(PropertiesValueResolver.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.config.AttributeDefinition.resolve(AttributeDefinition.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.puparser.PersistenceUnitXmlParser.parsePU(PersistenceUnitXmlParser.java:220)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.puparser.PersistenceUnitXmlParser.parse(PersistenceUnitXmlParser.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.parse(PersistenceUnitParseProcessor.java:217)
    ... 8 more

13:16:10,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 8) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\""}}
13:16:10,962 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war in 338ms
13:16:10,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 8) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"

[2014-05-30 01:16:11,000] Artifact XXX-webapp:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2014-05-30 01:16:11,000] Artifact XXX-webapp:war: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\""}}
```

I checked in file 'persistence.xml' for this ${XXX.datasource}, and replaced it with static reference to xxDS which I have configured in standalone.xml, I clean and install maven project, but still got this same error. I don't get it, can anyone help?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve expression: ${XXX.datasource}` Clearly u have unresolved variable either in your persistence.xml or standalone.xml

Comment: C:/serwers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/XXX-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/XXX-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml is this path valid ?

Comment: yep - I double checked this.